# ACR User dialogs - How to Change spinner color in Xamarin.Forms IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, spinner, loader

How do I change the default color of the Loading Spinner in ACR user dialogs. Anyone know how to change the Loading Spinner color in Xamarin.Forms IOS?

Comment: Hi, do you mean this [Xamarin.Forms ActivityIndicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/activityindicator)?

Comment: No. I am using Acr.UserDialogs plugin to display a loading indicator.